# Default image for woocommerce category products

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, categories

I am setting up a woocommerce site. I am having a lot of products, and I don't have image for every product.

My question:

Is there a way to use the category image as product image for products which currently have no image?

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-the-placeholder-image/

Comment: that would add 1 image for all products that dont have images. I am lookin for something like : if product has no img =>use the product category img

Comment: We can set category image for product if product will not have image.But my question is this one product could be assigned for more than one category.In that case which category image will come in product image.